# Add a close button for a task module in ms teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am investigating if it's applicable to have a cancel/ close button on our html page inside taskmodule so it can actually close the task module?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's entirely possible to do this. Basically, in order to close your task module in any way, you make a call from within the web page (in script), to:
`microsoftTeams.tasks.submitTask`

submitTask takes two parameters. The first is any object you want to return back to the caller (whatever opened your task module). For instance, if you have a Tab in your app, and the Tab opens the task module to app a new entry  to a database, you could pass that new item back to the opening Tab by passing it as `microsoftTeams.tasks.submitTask(newItem);`

You can see more about this [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-task-module-csharp/blob/master/Microsoft.Teams.Samples.TaskModule.Web/Views/Home/CustomForm.cshtml#L22).

If you have nothing at all to send back, you can simply call `microsoftTeams.tasks.submitTask(null);`. In this case, it will do nothing but close the task module, which sounds like what you're trying to do.

Comment: sure, glad to help

Comment: In a case you are using an Adaptive Card.
Add 
action(Button) with "type": "Action.Submit", 
and
"msteams": {
            "type": "task/submit"
          },
"action_name": "closePopup"

action_name is an custom param.
On a server side you just know that for this submit type you don't need return anything. 
So TaskModule will be closed